# Can I do an easy init a string with format using @" 

Tags: objective-c, string

when defining a string in Objective-C, can I do an easy assignment using a string format, such as

```
NSString *myVar = @"My String has %d words", 4;
```

Comment: I find it difficult to believe you could not find an answer to this question with some basic searching or self help, and have to ask on SO.

Comment: Did you try doing this?  If so, what happened?  If not, why not?

Answer (score 8):

nope

```
NSString *myVar = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"My String has %d words", 4];
```